# Making a grouped barchart with matplotlib,

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to make a bar chart where netwrok is in the x axis and spend is in the y axis, but I also want to group the bar chart of the same network together, even if they have the same month, how can i do this? some of the networks do not have spend one whole month This will be run monthly so separating by month in this one instance will not work, I want to make it as automated as possible

| month | network | spend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | CNBC | 24 |
| 9 | BBC | 10 |
| 10 | BBC | 10 |
| 9 | Com | 10 |
| 9 | BLOM | 10 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pivot your dataframe and then plot. Consider this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'month': [9,9,10,9,9], 'network': ['CNBC', 'BBC', 'BBC', 'Com', 'BLOM'], 'spend': [24,10,10,10,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df.pivot(index='network', columns='month', values='spend')
df.plot.bar()
plt.show(block=True)
```

This will show you the grouped plot as

[image: Grouped Plot]

In my opinion, stacked plot looks even better for your data. If you want stacked plot. Just change it to `df.plot.bar(stacked=True)` 
[image: Stacked Plot]